# No matches found for the given name

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, resources

The project was an import of an earlier working project, but after the import one of several errors was

```
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name                'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.   styles.xml
```

In following instructions from other posts

I've re-imported/re-downloaded the appcompat support library

Added it to the build path(added it's jar files to the libraries / added the project and its jar files to order and export) in different ways

All my SDK's are installed and up to date

And cleaned the project several times

Really not sure what else could be done any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do next:

```
  Project-> properties->Android. In the section library "Add" and choose "appCompat"
```

and

```
  Project-> properties->Java Build Path->check Android Dependencies.
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: It worked i'd like to upvote your answer but i've not enough reputation, thank you very much

Comment: welcome.. but u can mark it as right solution.. there will be a check click on that only